# Is there a way to point to the correct gcc version?

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors

First time post at Stackoverflow so thank you in advance.  I am trying to install the r package called sm or any package that needs to be compiled.   I truly would appreciate any guidance possible as this is preventing me from compiling r packages and RMarkdown files as well.

I receive an error message that appears to point to the incorrect version of gcc on my machine.  I read a different post that said I needed to add the path to gcc to my .bash_profile so I amended it as so:

## export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.1.0/:/usr/local/bin/"
export PATH

I receive this error message:

- installing *source* package ‘sm’ ...
  ** package ‘sm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-7 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c fgamma.c -o fgamma.o
  ** libs
  /bin/sh: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gcc-7: No such file or directory
  make: *** [fgamma.o] Error 127
  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sm’

Comment: You pasted 2 different ways of amending the `PATH` environment variable. Which one is in effect? The first one looks correct to me, because it has a directory you presumably want to be searched for `gcc` executable *before* the old value of `PATH`. Also, I would recommend editing your question with additional details like what distribution and package manager you are using and adding appropriate tags.

Comment: It worked!  Thanks so much.  This made my day.